# Designing 3NF Database

Tags: sqlite, relational-database

I am designing a 3nf (Relational) database for insurance management system.

The following is my brief;

> The system must provides means of associating their customers and cars with recorded accidents. Each customer has name, address and can have one or mpre driving licenses. One customer can own 1 or more cars. A car has a reg no, model and year of manufacture. Each car has associated with it zero to any number of recorded accidents. Each accident has a report number, date, location and an amount of damage.
>   I have complied the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(CID int primary key, Address varchar (50),Name varchar (50));
CREATE TABLE Driving_Lisc (CID int, Lisc_NO int, primary key);
CREATE TABLE Car(Reg_No varchar (20) primary key, Model nvarchar (20),year int)
CREATE TABLE Owns(CID int, Reg_No nvarchar(20) composite key)
CREATE Accident (Reported_No int primary key, Location varchar (40), date date)
Participated(CID int, Reg_No nvarchar(20), Reported No int primary key, damage Amount float)
```

I'm looking to see if I have correctly complied these database in order to completed SQLite queries.

Comment: What is your question? Where do you have problems that your teaching material does not cover?

Comment: I am wondering if I have created the correct tables

Comment: Hi. "3NF" means something. But you don't say anything relevant to that meaning in your question. If you want to know if your tables are 3NF then show why they are. If you want to embody your design in SQL, write some code. If you want feedback, give & justify your decisions following your textbook--not just milestones. If you are stuck then ask a specific question about a specific problem in a specific part of your design. PS Please clarify via post edits not comments. PS Please read the edit help re formating line breaks & code blocks. And look at the formatted version before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **NO** that is the code will not work using SQLite due to :-

In `CREATE TABLE Driving_Lisc (CID int, Lisc_NO int, primary key);` there is an extraneous **`,`** that separates `primary key` or that the column name and type have been omitted following the comma.

In `CREATE TABLE Owns(CID int, Reg_No nvarchar(20) composite key)` **composite** is not an SQLite keyword, one would be expected following the column type ('nvarchar(20)').

In `CREATE Accident (Reported_No int primary key, Location varchar (40), date date)` you are not specifying what to CREATE. You likely want `CREATE TABLE Accident (Reported_No int primary key, Location varchar (40), date date)`

using `Participated(CID int, Reg_No nvarchar(20), Reported No int primary key, damage Amount float)` will result in a syntax error as there are no SQL keywords that indicate what is to be done. You possibly want `CREATE TABLE Participated(CID int, Reg_No nvarchar(20), Reported No int primary key, damage Amount float)`